# How to use Ant mail task? what are the manditory inputs?

Tags: email, scripting, ant, automation, outlook

I am using ms- outlook. What are the manditory inputs for this Ant task and how can i find my mailhost and mailport number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Ant's [Mail task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mail.html), the following information is required:

- `from` attribute or `<from>` nested element.
- `tolist`, `cclist`, or `bcclist` attributes or their equivalent nested elements `<to>`, `<cc>`, or `<bcc>`.
- either `message` or `messagefile` attribute, alternatively nested `<message>` element.

If you SMTP server requires authentication, you must provide `user` and `password` attributes.

Basically these are required for any mail client.

Mail host and port, the address of an SMTP server, you can get from your system administrator.